# INNER JOIN OPENROWSET for VBA Programming?

Tags: excel, ibm-midrange, updating, vba

In SQL programming, there is a code : INNER JOIN OPENROWSET to join table in excel worksheet with MSSQL database.

My question is What codes in VBA Programming that have the same function as INNER JOIN OPENROWSET in MSSQL but the function is joining table in excel worksheet with AS400 database.